# Validating email in django query

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I validate a email field and update another field based on that in a single 'django' query. Can I do it with Regex.

Comment: Please explain your problem with more details

Comment: I have Model with email and is_valid field. i need to update the is_valid field based on weather email is valid or not in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it like:

```
TempUser.objects.exclude(email__regex=r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$').update(is_valid=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set is_valid field initially false. You will only show the email field in the template. When anyone fill up the the email field and submit the form then you can valid the email. If it is valid then you can set is_valid field set true. If it is not then you have to render the same page once again.